# How can I rewrite onkeydown on the html element?

Tags: jquery, html

I inherited an application that implements disabling F5 in a window popup.

```
<body onkeydown="disableF5();">
```

However if the user clicks below the body in the window and presses F5 the page will still refresh.

I moved the function call to

```
<html onkeydown="disableF5();">
```

and now F5 is disabled and everything is working as expected.

However this is not the best place to have code and I would prefer it if I could do something like below in my `<script>` section so I can add comments and perhaps move it to an external file.

```
$("html").attr("onkeydown", "disableF5();");
```

This snippet of jQuery does not work as expected however so I'm currently stuck at the moment.

Is there a way I can set the attributes of the `<html>` element?

**Edit:** I thought I would throw my disableF5() function in here.

```
function disableF5() {  
   if (window.event && window.event.keyCode == 116) { 
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        window.event.returnValue = false;
        window.event.keyCode = 0;
        window.status = "F5 is disabled on all popups";
        return false;
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('html').bind('keydown', function(){ disableF5(); });
```

See the [documentation for $.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

**Edit –** Moderately verbose explanation:

HTML `onstuff` attributes are evaluated as the DOM is loaded. Adding them post-factum doesn't have any effect. Thus, proper JS event binding must be used.

Answer (score 2):

This works in latest Chrome and FireFox and seems cleaner than `bind` to me:

```
$(document.documentElement).keydown(disableF5);
```

Comment: Have a +1 for bleeding edge … In a scenario where functions named `disableF5` are present, the exclusive use of Chrome/FF latest seems pretty unlikely though :D

Comment: Yeah, I'm sad to say that all the users are, of course, on IE.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('html').bind('keydown', function() { disableF5(); }));
```